Re-launch an existing task in recent apps from a service
I am trying to launch a specific app that appears on the recent apps screen, from a service, given the app's package name. The following usually works:
context.startActivity(new Intent().setPackage(packageName).setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is required when launching an activity from outside an activity context (in this case an Accessibility service). Even though this would imply that a NEW task will be created, it successfully re-launches the task that was visible in recents, if it already existed. If not, it creates a new one.
However, the above does NOT work when the app in question was originally launched from a different app. For example, if com.android.settings was originally launched from a system notification or from within another app, the above code will launch a new instance of com.android.settings instead of bringing up the one that was already showing in recent apps. I have tried adding different flags to no avail.
Does anyone have a solution for this or at least explain why this happens?
EDIT:
I am adding more steps on how to reproduce this and the output of adb shell dumpsys activity activities.
Steps to reproduce:

Clear all tasks
Try to uninstall a device admin app directly from the launcher by dragging it to the "uninstall" button. It will fail and show a notification.
Tap the notification to open up the Settings app to the device admin page.
Launch com.android.settings from code:

context.startActivity(new Intent().setPackage("com.android.settings").setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
OR
context.startActivity(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.settings"));


Open up the recent apps screen to verify whether there are now 2 Settings tasks present.

Here is the output of "adb shell dumpsys activity activities" for:
Settings opened through the failed device admin uninstallation.
Settings opened both through the failed device admin uninstallation and also opened by our own code.

In the situation you describe, is the app that was launched (example: Settings) running in its own task? or running as part of the task that launched it? You can tell this by doing adb shell dumpsys activity activities and you can see the list of tasks and the activities that belong to those tasks. Please do this and add the analysis to the question.

@DavidWasser please see my latest edit. I added two different outputs of dumpsys activity activities. I'm not 100% sure how to read it so I just pasted the whole thing.

I'm confused. In the first linked dumpsys output, all I see is the nexuslauncher task. I don't see the Settings activity anywhere. Are you sure that the Settings activity was running when you produced this dumpsys output?

Yes, I am certain. I cleared the recent apps screen, then got it to be the only thing showing up in the recent apps screen. It was opened from a notification from the system about a device admin app failing to be uninstalled. Can you try to replicate opening it that way? This was on a Google Pixel 8 Pro.

I don't understand. Are you saying that in the first case (launched via notification), you have a task in the list of recent tasks that is the Settings app? Because in the dumpsys output there is only one task and that is the Android launcher (HOME screen). Please elaborate, this makes no sense. Maybe add relevant screenshots

Because I can imagine that Android is launching Settings from the system Notification using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS, so it doesn't actually create an entry in the list of recent tasks at all, which is why it doesn't show up in the dumpsys output. If this is the case, you cannot return the user to this task because it no longer exists.

Yes. I'm not sure why it's not in the output but I can still see it in recents and manually return to it by tapping on it.

Please try to get the dumpsys output again when it is in that state. The task MUST show up in the dumpsys output if it is in the list of recent tasks.
